# Error, 'ASK CLI v1 is not functional' in Visual Studio Code

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Here's the entire error message....

Command 'ASK: Deploy the skill' resulted in an error (ASK CLI v1 is not functional. Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /q /s /c "ask init -l" error: unknown option '-l' )

Happens when I 'ASK deploy' or any ASK command. Anybody have any ideas what that means?

TIA!!

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting downvoted, this is a legit question and I am having the error as well. I see the error is caused by this specific line: "ask init -l". This is supposed to list the profiles, but even when I run it directly in bash or PowerShell it fails. It is saying the -l switch is unknown when it is supposed to be a valid command.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and assuming you are a windows user, this may be your issue.

Before you install ASK-CLI on Windows, you **must install the Node.js windows-build-tools package**. Before you install windows-build-tools, make sure you have the version of Node.js that the package requires. If you have already installed ASK-CLI you need to uninstall it. Then install it again after you have installed windows-build-tools.

To install windows-build-tools, first open PowerShell with the Run as Administrator option, then type `npm install -g --production windows-build-tools`.

After I did this, I had to delete and recreate my ASK project, then my ASK deployments started working.

Reference: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a step by step to setup a new environment:

1. npm install -g --production windows-build-tools
2. npm install -g ask-cli
3. ask configure
4. npm install -g lambda-local

Please assure that you are running the command as Administrator or using sudo on Linux.